# How to Bind "Up" in a WPF DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I have an collection I use as the `ItemSource` of my `DataGrid`.  The ItemSource is a list of custom objects (Cars), and each Car object has a list of `Licensor` objects as a property.  Within each `Licensor` object there is a dictionary collection that must be displayed in the DataGrid.  So the objects would look something like this:

- ### Car
- int CarId
- string Name
- string Make
- int Year
- List Licensors

  -
- ### Licensor
- int LicensorId
- string Name
- Dictionary (int, string) Licenses

The DataGrid displays the first 2 properties of the Car object collection in a `TextBox`, but I need to display a value from the dictionary property of the Licensor list whose key is the Car ID.  In other words, I need to bind "up" from a `DataGridTemplateColumn`.  So my DataGrid looks like this:

```
<DataGrid Name="MyDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Car Name">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DateGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Car Make">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Make}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DateGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Licensor Name">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Licensors}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DateGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <!-- THE BELOW COLUMN IS THE ONE THAT NEEDS TO BIND 'UP' -->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="First License">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Licensors}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Licenses[{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=DataContext.CarId}][0]}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DateGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The last column in the code is the column I need to bind "up" back to the parent object to access the `CarId` property to use as the Dictionary's key value.  Has anyone done this before?  The code I have for the last column does not work, my thought was to get the ancestor of the current column to access the DataGrid's main source or context but that did not work.

Thanks!

Comment: This is where a proper View-Model (of the MVVM pattern) can be extremely helpful.  You could make a `CarVm` class that represents the data needed to properly display a `Car` in the view.  It can wrap a car, but can have additional properties, like the ones you are talking about, than can use whatever coding logic you want to calculate.

Comment: I can't make any sense out of your classes. Your binding assumes that the thing that owns the `Cars` collection owns a `Licenses` collection -- is that correct, or a typo, or a misunderstanding on your part of how bindings work? Can you show C# code for retrieving the license for a CarId? Is it possible to give `Car` a property that returns that value? "Up binding" isn't a term of art in WPF, so it's not at all helpful in understandig what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks @Bradley Uffner, I am using a ViewModel for my window, the VM, and the VM utilizes a wrapper for the Cars object.  I was hoping there is a straight XAML way of doing an "up" binding without having to change the wrapper much.  All of the data I need is in the main Car object, so I was trying to avoid having to create additional properties or methods to obtain the data.  But maybe sounds like that might be the best option?

Comment: `Car` and `Licensor` are two separate classes.  `Car` has a list of `Licensor` objects though.  In real words, if selling a car there could be multiple owners and licenses through the history of that car.  The `List<Licensor>` collection is this.  In terms of the DataGrid code I posted, in this case, each Car object does own a collection of Licensors, since each car outputted can have a different list of owners and licenses..  Code for retrieving a CarId comes straight from a repository hooked to EF.  It is just a DTO object, no logic in the DTO and the repo method used is a simple EF query

Comment: Code to get a license from a CarId would be something like `string license = Cars.Where(c => c.CarId == 1).Licensors.FirstOrDefault().Licenses[some car ID][0];

Comment: Please help me understand why there are two different CarIDs in that statement.

Comment: Do you ever use any Licensor other than the first?

Comment: That was a bad example, the point is I need to be able to get a property from upper level object `Car` and use it as the key value in my dictionary.  So instead of `some car ID` it could be another property coming from `Car`.

Comment: Maybe providing a screenshot of the UI would help us better understand what you are trying to do,  how the different classes are used, and where you want to pull values from.

Comment: @J-man There is no general answer to that question, so I've voted to close the question. I could help you solve the specific problem you have, if you were willing to provide enough information -- though I think by far the best solution to that may be to redesign your classes.

Comment: That's ok.  It is a complicated matter.  I can't change the design of the classes unfortunately, one limitation is they need to be fixed.  In the end, just wondering if it is possible to bind "up"

Comment: As Bradley said, the "bind-up" should definitely be done in your VM. That is the purpose of the VM.